# Is it correct to say "from first day of your job"?

Tags: sentence-structure

I want to say:

> You can't make money **from first day of your job**

Is that correct to say **from first day of your job**?

Also does it make sense to say:

> You can't make money in the first year/ first two years of your job.

Answer (score 1):

More idiomatic would be:

- From **the** first day of your job

But your second sentence is perfectly fine.